# What is the '.save_docker/' folder? Can I delete it?

Tags: linux, docker

After using docker, I found my disk space had been eat a lot. I searched google to resolve the problem, found a post said this is because of aufs & devicemapper.

Now I found a folder named `.save_docker` in `/home`. In this folder, there is a folder names aufs, the aufs folder almost 16 G.

I want to know what is the folder and can I delete it?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save_docker` doesn't seem used in [docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=save_docker) or [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=save_docker) or [compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=save_docker&type=Code) or [machine](https://github.com/docker/machine/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=save_docker).

But even before trying to remove it, check if you have:

- [stopped containers](https://github.com/wsargent/docker-cheat-sheet#delete-stopped-containers) that you could remove

  ```
  docker rm -v $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)
  ```
- dangling images

  ```
  docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
  ```

For that, see [`HardySimpson/docker-cleanup`](https://github.com/HardySimpson/docker-cleanup) bash script.
Or my [`dcl` bash script](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/master/dcl).

Then check if you still have a disk space issue, and if `/home/.save_docker` was modified in any way.

Comment: I don't there's any need for the for loop in removing dangling images; `docker rmi` can take a list of images to remove.

Comment: @AdrianMouat True. I have amended the answer accordingly

Comment: @VonC After I removed the exited containers, free a lot of disk space, thank you.